# Implement SLI for Application/Service Availability using Promethues

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, spring-webflux, spring-boot-actuator, promql

The task is to implement SLI for Application/Service **Availability** for 5 mins using Prometheus but the catch is not using the Prometheus **UP** metric, Here I have to use the spring health(UP/Down) metric to track availability. So please can anyone help here, Thanks In advance.

**Availability result should be in 0/1**
0 - Not available
1 - available

So to expose health metric on Prometheus I tried the below code.
Or is there any better way to calculate availability using spring health metrics?
*Note*: Cannot use any prober as it is restricted in business.

```java
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class MyHealthMetricsExportConfiguration {


    public MyHealthMetricsExportConfiguration(MeterRegistry registry, HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint) {
        // This example presumes common tags (such as the app) are applied elsewhere
        Gauge.builder("health", healthEndpoint, this::getStatusCode).strongReference(true).register(registry);
    }

    private int getStatusCode(HealthEndpoint health) {
        Status status = health.health().getStatus();
        if (Status.UP.equals(status)) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Now it is showing health gauze value = 1, as localhost service is up and running. I have 2 instances running locally.

I tried the below promql query

`sum by (application) (avg_over_time(health{application="My Service"}[5m]))` so my both instances are running it is giving 2 as value but I need the result to consider the application as a whole, i.e if both instances are running the result should be 1. And If one of the instances is down the result should be also 1.
And if both instances are down promql query should return 0 as a result.

How to achieve this, Any help will be appreciated, Thanks In advance.

Comment: you want to get a result from the promql query that says whether at least one instance is up? and in that case to get 1? also, how are you using the query later? (maybe there's a fix in that direction)

Comment: Hi @NoamYizraeli, Thanks for your reply. Yes, I want query which records at least one instance is up or not and in that case result should be 1.  I will use that query as a Prometheus rule to calculate result.

Comment: Great! if you want to use the query for a Prometheus rule you can check whether the value is less than 1, isn't it? once the average over 5 min falls under 1 that means your instance was down, though in that case maybe avg_over_time isn't that good, unless you want to smooth short times when both were down?

Comment: Hi @NoamYizraeli, Thanks Actually I am new to the Prometheus I don't know much about the promql query, I gone through some ans on other posts thats why I have used avg_over_time. Please suggest me which function I can use here for better result and How we can modify this query for better result. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, there are a few options:

I'll be assuming the `health` metric you're using is similar to the `up` metric usually present with the common Prometheus exporters.
To the best of my understanding, the **first option** is the better one for your use case.

## when service might constantly restart

is that case both instances might be restarting due to bad data or config and even if at any moment one would be up you'd want to know of such behavior, in that case calculating the average over time may be better but you'd want to get the max of the two instances to verify that at least one was running correctly: `max by (application) (avg_over_time(health{application="My Service"}[5m]))`

the complete rule example:

```yaml
groups:
- name: MyServiceRuleGroup
  rules:
  - alert: ServiceUptimeIsCompromised
    expr: max by (application) (avg_over_time(health{application="My Service"}[5m])) < 1
    for: 1m
    labels:
      severity: critical
    annotations:
      summary: service {{ $labels.application }} uptime has fallen below the threshold
```

the reason to use `max` over `avg` is to figure out whether at least one of the instances was up completely on its own (which is presumably what we want to check) if we'd like to know the general state of the application we'd use `avg` (theoretically only, this isn't the best option for that need)
if you'd want to check a more immediate fluctuation you might reduce the time span to average the results (in the query itself)

## for more permanent issues:

this query would make more use when the app doesn't have an auto-heal solution in place, for example if a process or server crashes and needs to be started up manually.

You can check `sum by(application)(health{application="My Service"}) < 1`

The complete rule example:

```yaml
groups:
- name: MyServiceRuleGroup
  rules:
  - alert: ServiceUptimeIsCompromised
    expr: sum by(application)(health{application="My Service"}) < 1
    for: 5m
    labels:
      severity: critical
    annotations:
      summary: service {{ $labels.application }} uptime has fallen below the threshold
```

If you wish to be informed as the service was down you might change the `groups[i].rules[j].for` variable to `1m`. Or you might keep it at `5m` if you only want to be informed of prolonged downtime by an error or other unhealable issue

Comment: Hi @NoamYizraeli, Thanks for the detailed answers, Will be using the 1st query for my task. I have less than 15 reputations so not able to upvote the answer.

Comment: Hi @NoamYizraeli, I am using gauze metric to expose the health metric to prometheus as mentioned in question code. So when I run the application the prometheus instance will return health gauze vale as 1(In UP case) , and when I stop application, it will not display anything ie. (In down case). So Whatever I am doing is it sufficient to make conclusion that my application is available and UP ? As I will not get metric value as 0 in    localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus instance. Any suggestions here will be helpful . Thanks

Comment: just to verify, when running `health == 0` in prometheus you get nothing\an empty result?

Comment: Yes, getting no result. ie. no data in Prometheus console

Comment: I thank you for trying, you can accept the answer which will help others recognise a helpful answer (if this is one) and give me some rep .regarding the issue, in that case, a solution I needed also was `count(health{application="My Service"}==1)/count(health{application="My Service"}) < 0.5` (cause 1/2 is 0.5. if a different instance count is required then use a different fraction), prometheus knows how many endpoints should answer so we need to check what's their active percentage

Comment: Hi @NoamYizraeli, How to unit test above mentioned code that is HealthMetricsConfiguration class like how we can check UP and DOEN status in spring boot test

Comment: sorry I'm not that familiar with that, maybe in the near future I'll try and post an update